# Is it possible to use a database link between an oracle database and a postgresql database on different physical servers

Tags: java, sql, oracle, postgresql, dblink

I've trying to streamline an intranet application where some of the data is stored locally on the postgresql database of the intranet server and other related data is stored in our enterprise oracle 10g2r2 database.

What I would like to do is create a view on either database box wouldn't really matter that combines for simplicity sake one table from each database into a flat view of both.  This would allow me to then make simple queries from within the intranet application.

Currently I'm having to pull in the data from both db's into an object structure and then run finds/searches against these objects.  I really don't like doing it this way and would love to be able to create a view.

If this isn't possible, then maybe some suggestions on the best way to handle this situation.

My intranet stack s  Linux, postgresql, tomcat (java), apache.   And again the oracle db is a 10gr2

tim

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to connect from Oracle to postgresql, http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14232/toc.htm, this forum can also help: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=63

Comment: Thank you very much!  I took a quick look and this does appear to be able to do this. I'll have to read through the docs first thing monday.